# wget unable to download file

Tags: linux, docker, openshift, wget

I'm trying to build an image with docker build in Jenkins container running on openshift cluster. 
The docker file is as simple as below:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi

RUN dnf install -y wget
RUN dnf update -y

RUN wget --debug http://coin-or-tools.github.io/ThirdParty-Metis/metis-4.0.3.tar.gz
RUN wget --debug http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz
```

The first wget command runs without any issues.
The problem is caused by the second command - it is just hangs on with constant retries.

The docker server version is 18.09.2 running on Alpine Linux 3.9. Also I tried with 18.09.9, 19.03.5, 19.3.11 - the result is the same.

The output of running two above **wget** commands is as below:

```
Step 4/5 : RUN wget --debug http://coin-or-tools.github.io/ThirdParty-Metis/metis-4.0.3.tar.gz
 ---> Running in 45cfae4bb4da
[91mDEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.5 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /root/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
[0m[91mconverted 'http://coin-or-tools.github.io/ThirdParty-Metis/metis-4.0.3.tar.gz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://coin-or-tools.github.io/ThirdParty-Metis/metis-4.0.3.tar.gz' (UTF-8)
Converted file name 'metis-4.0.3.tar.gz' (UTF-8) -> 'metis-4.0.3.tar.gz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968)
[0m[91m--2020-06-09 11:41:36--  http://coin-or-tools.github.io/ThirdParty-Metis/metis-4.0.3.tar.gz
Resolving coin-or-tools.github.io (coin-or-tools.github.io)... [0m[91m185.199.110.153, 185.199.111.153, 185.199.109.153, ...
Caching coin-or-tools.github.io => 185.199.110.153 185.199.111.153 185.199.109.153 185.199.108.153
Connecting to coin-or-tools.github.io (coin-or-tools.github.io)|185.199.110.153|:80... [0m[91mconnected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00005633fa9d4aa0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /ThirdParty-Metis/metis-4.0.3.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.5 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: coin-or-tools.github.io
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... [0m[91m
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: application/gzip
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Nov 2019 10:00:30 GMT
ETag: "5dcbd43e-7f980"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 11:26:35 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 4934:54FD:5276E3:699E9E:5EDF6F93
Content-Length: 522624
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 11:41:37 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-dfw18644-DFW
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1591702897.931460,VS0,VE157
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Fastly-Request-ID: 25537d6f9a537a4b935b49dee5b190506508929c

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Length: 522624 (510K) [application/gzip]
[0m[91mSaving to: 'metis-4.0.3.tar.gz'

     0K .......... ..[0m[91m........ .......... ........[0m[91m.. .[0m[91m.........  9% 27.5M 0s[0m[91m
    50K ...[0m[91m....... ......[0m[91m.... ........[0m[91m.. ......[0m[91m.... .[0m[91m....[0m[91m..... 19% 8.97M 0s
   100K ...[0m[91m....... .[0m[91m......... .....[0m[91m..... .......[0m[91m... .....[0m[91m..... 29% 32.7M 0s
   150K ...[0m[91m....... .........[0m[91m.[0m[91m .......... ......[0m[91m.... ....[0m[91m...... 39% 11.2M 0s
   200K ..[0m[91m........ ......[0m[91m....[0m[91m .......... .......[0m[91m... .......... 48% 17.2M 0s
   250K ..[0m[91m........ .....[0m[91m..... ....[0m[91m...... ..........[0m[91m .......... 58% 19.9M 0s
   300K ...[0m[91m....... .........[0m[91m. ...[0m[91m....... .......... ..[0m[91m........ 68% 20.1M 0s
   350K .......... ....[0m[91m...... .......... .......... .......... 78% 6.38M 0s
   400K .......[0m[91m... .......... ...[0m[91m....... .........[0m[91m. .......... 88% 15.7M 0s
   450K ...[0m[91m....... ..........[0m[91m .......... ......[0m[91m.... .......... 97% 16.5M 0s[0m[91m
   500K ..........                                            100% 12.9M=0.04s

[0m[91m2020-06-09 11:41:37 (14.1 MB/s) - 'metis-4.0.3.tar.gz' saved [522624/522624]

[0mRemoving intermediate container 45cfae4bb4da
 ---> 2c819d73e9a5
Step 5/5 : RUN wget --debug http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz
 ---> Running in c5704353a863
[91mDEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.5 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /root/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
converted 'http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz' (UTF-8)
Converted file name 'MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz' (UTF-8) -> 'MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968)
--2020-06-09 11:41:38--  http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz
[0m[91mResolving mumps.enseeiht.fr (mumps.enseeiht.fr)... [0m[91m147.127.176.144
Caching mumps.enseeiht.fr => 147.127.176.144
Connecting to mumps.enseeiht.fr (mumps.enseeiht.fr)|147.127.176.144|:80... [0m[91mconnected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000558cc5f90980 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /MUMPS_4.10.0.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.5 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: mumps.enseeiht.fr
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---

>>>>>>>> HERE IS WHERE WGET HANGS ON <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... [0m[91mRead error (Connection timed out) in headers.
[0m[91mClosed fd 3
Retrying.
```

On another openshift cluster this behaviour does not appear.

My questions are: what can cause wget to hang on on this particular URL? 
Is it possible that some changes of openshift configuration needed? What changes? 
If not - then what reason do you see taking into account different behaviour on two clusters and failure across different versions of docker?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try by enable verbose log `wget -v`?

Comment: Hi Dai! Thank you for response! It is enabled by default according to wget docs(https://www.computerhope.com/unix/wget.htm) but I have added the option. The output absolutely the same

Comment: Another point, you have `/root/.wget-hsts` file, not sure any restrict setting in this file for your target site. You can try with `wget --no-hsts`. Another option, you may try with single bad wget command, see what happen.

Comment: No this option doesn't help also